# My value gets Wrong if I use ++ operand with my pointer

Tags: c++

My Code is:

```
int abdul = 11;
    int *ptr = &abdul;
//Problem is here
//  *ptr += 1;
//  *ptr++;
    cout << &*ptr;
    cout << "\n" << &abdul;
    cout << *ptr;
}
```

If I use `*ptr +=1` it added 1 in abdul location value. But if I use `*ptr++` it gives some random value.

When I use `*ptr += 1` the output is correct. But using increment or decrement operator value gets wrong. I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `*ptr++` is treated as `*(ptr++)`. The pointer is incremented first and then dereferenced. In your case, that causes undefined behavior since `ptr` points to a single object.

To increment the value of the object that `ptr` points to, use `(*ptr)++` or `++(*ptr)`.

It's better to be clear about your intention using parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

[Operator precendece](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `*ptr++` is evaluated as `*(ptr++)`. But you want `(*ptr)++` Just add some parantheses to show the compiler what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [Operator Precedense](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) what happens is you increment the address doing `ptr++` and then you dereference it by doing `*ptr`.

what you can do is use prefix increment : `++*ptr`